# LaTex How to remove trailing zeros in scientific notion

Tags: latex

When using large numbers I'd like to use scinetific notation in LaTex. However, because of the trailing zeros it gets worse.
E.g.

```
\num[scientific-notation=true,  exponent-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}]{250000000000000000000}
```

[image]

Comment: If these figures aren't significant, you could input it as `\num[scientific-notation=true,  exponent-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}]{25e19}`

Answer (score 0):

If these figures aren't significant, you could input it as

```
\num[scientific-notation=true,  exponent-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}]{25e19}
```